# setting options while installing or after installing App

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to set the language for one time once the user downloaded the app and started using it, for only first time. but not all the time he use the app. How can i do that?

like how we get select language options , while installing Microsoft products, etc

is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

you can control that when you application apears. Did you know about property lists?
You could use it. Or maybe you can create a file with Core data with name Configs. You need to check if field is blank and case yes, open a viewControllerChangeLanguange.After select save the data and start your application. Remember, everytime you start you will check your file. Case exists, set current language.Case not, invoke an interface to user select a language. All the controller could be made by just a file config.